# How to remove spaces between inside a quotation with a regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I have some text here:

```
... che si concluse con la " desegregazione " degli autobus.
```

What regular expression can I use to grab these spaces and turn this into:

```
... che si concluse con la "desegregazione" degli autobus.
```

I was thinking of something like `(?<=\".{1,20})\"` (sorry if it's clunky, I'm a beginner), but apparently Regex doesn't accept quantifiers inside of lookbehinds, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: input and output are the same apparently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
"\s*([^"]*?)\s*"
```

Replace with `"$1"`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J8vQSZ/1)

**Details**

- `"` - a double quotation mark
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([^"]*?)`  - Group 1 (`$1` in the replacement pattern refers to this value): any 0+ chars other than `"` (see `[^"]` negated character class), as few as possible (see `*?` non-greedy quantifier)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `"` - a double quotation mark.